# Minimal (numerical) example for simple neural net

Tags: neural-network

I‘m looking for a good minimal numerical example for teaching how a neural net is solved. Basically the idea is to see how the hidden layers (i.e. the weights) work using „pen and paper“.

Back in Uni I did similar things „by hand“ for OLS regression on a 3x3 matrix.

Does anyone know about a good source/example for neural nets?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/55099/layer-notation-for-feed-forward-neural-networks/55109#55109
This might be helpful if you mean something like this. Also, I've seen something before but I can't remember where!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the work of [Andrew Trask](https://twitter.com/iamtrask?lang=en) in this book.

Most detailed work on this that I have seen.

[grokking Deep Learning](https://www.manning.com/books/grokking-deep-learning)